# How to make recursive function that multiply two positive numbers without using mutiplication operator

Tags: logic

Some one ask a this question from me. I am confuse how it is possible to multiply two numbers without using multiplication operator? Plz share you idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its so simple. see this code:

```
int multiplication(int a, int b){
   if(b==1|| b==0) 
      return a; 
   else 
   return a+multiplication(a,--b); 
}
```

I have not tested it. Just share it for idea.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the terms you are multiplying are non-negative integers, you don't even need full addition, just a successor function (i.e. the ability to add one). That's because ...

- `a*b` is the same as `add together b lots of a`
- `a+b` is the same as `add 1 to a, b times`

So you could program `a*b` that with nested loops like this:

```
answer = 0
for iMultiply from 1 to b
   for iAdd from 1 to a
      answer++
   next iAdd
next iMultiply
return answer
```